# VueJS: apply mixin to async component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `Webpack 2` and importing my components via special `require` syntax.

There are over 100 components, but only 5-10 used at a time. Most of them (but not all) partially have same functionality like props and lifecycle hooks.

Here is code:

```
// app.js
...

Vue.component("foo", resolve => {
  require(['./components/foo.vue'], resolve);
});

...
```

I want to apply mixin to async component, but how to do that? `Global mixin` apply to all components, but that's not what I need.

I found that [feature request](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5319), but it closed.

Answer (score 0):

I found some creepy(?) solution, but **it works**:

```
// mixins.js
export default class Mixins {
   static fooMixin() {
     return {
       created: function () {
         console.log('mixin hook called');
       }
     }
   }
}

// app.js
Vue.component("foo", resolve => {
  require(['./components/foo.vue'], resolve);
});

// foo.vue
<script>
  import Mixins from "mixins";

  export default {
    ...
    mixins: [Mixins.fooMixin()]
  }
</script>
```

But I hope that there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Just use the mixin normally. The fact that the component is lazy-loaded should not change anything.

Comment: There are over 100 components, but only 5-10 used at a time. All of them partially have same functionality like props and lifecycle hooks. Lazy-load by design.

Comment: Well with small changes that is the correct answer 

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html - here you will see that you don't need class or that fancy stuff. You just provide a list of objects that will extend your component in a fashionable manner

Comment: I cannot provide anything to *async* component declaration, there is no syntax for that... :(